# how set delimitor for CSVRenderer in django rest_framework_csv?

Tags: python, django, csv, django-rest-framework

The rest_framework_csv uses module csv. I can not find the way to pass delimiter parameter for csv serialization.

I use the module as descriped here https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv . But I do not see the way to custom delimiter or set quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL .

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but [digging code](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv/blob/master/rest_framework_csv/renderers.py#L41) this snipped can help you in your issue:

```
from rest_framework_csv.renderers import CSVRenderer
class SpecialCharSeparator (CSVRenderer):
    def render(self, data, media_type=None, 
                     renderer_context=None, writer_opts=None):

        if writer_opts is None:
            writer_opts = {}

        new_writer_opts = {'delimiter':'|'}
        new_writer_opts.update( writer_opts )

        return (super(SpecialCharSeparator, self)
               .render(data, media_type, 
                      renderer_context, 
                      writer_opts=new_writer_opts)  #set your delimiter here
               )
```

Then use `SpecialCharSeparator` as rederer:

```
class MyView (APIView):
    renderer_classes = (r.SpecialCharSeparator, ) + ...
```

Comment: [here](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv/blob/master/rest_framework_csv/tests.py#L98) is the exact example how to do this